# how collect random id in jquery with .on('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment i have a list of elements and when clicked on one of them
it will get the number accordingly. However i need a different approach
that won't count the number of elements but returns the id number of that
specific element.

http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/

```
$('#outputData').on('click', 'li.element', function() {
    var num = $('#outputData li.element').index(this);

    alert(num);
    var loc = window.location + "";
    var pos = loc.indexOf('#');
    if (pos > -1) {
        loc = loc.substring(0, pos);
    };
    loc = loc + '#ti' + num;
    window.location = loc;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#outputData li').click(function() {
    var idOfLi = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(idOfLi);
  // rest of your code
});
```

and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/2/) is jsfiddle

Comment: thanks, that is what i was looking for. (ps. i can't vote up or such cos i haven't enough reputation)

Comment: yeah no problem ... do it once you got the enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/6/) with `ti`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/7/) without `ti`

## jQuery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/5/) With `ti`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FN4fy/4/) - Without `ti`

## Answer

You can use `this.id` if you want `ti#`, or `this.id.substring(2)` if you just want the number.

You can also use

```
window.location += "#"+this.id.substring(2);
```

If you want to go to the location on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

$(this).attr("id") will give the current element id, because event binded to li.

```
    $('#outputData').on('click', 'li.element', function() {
      window.location +=  $(this).attr("id") ;
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/FN4fy/8/)

```
$('#outputData').on('click', 'li.element', function() {
    var num = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(num); // returns id
    });
```

In case you want to fetch the number alone, then

```
$('#outputData').on('click', 'li.element', function() {
var num = parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/),10);
    alert(num); // returns number
});
```